# R Markdown: Set Start of the week date in parameters

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to set my Markdown parameter to the first day of the week. I tried executing the following code but there seems to be an error with date conversion.
Below is the markdown code.

````
---
title: "Sample Markdown"
author: "ABC"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
tables: yes
output: html_document
params:
  dts: 
    label: "Start Date"
    input: date
    value: !r as.Date(round(as.IDate(as.character(Sys.Date()), "%m-%d-%Y"), "week")-1)
    max: !r Sys.Date()
  dte: 
    label: "End Date"
    input: date
    value: !r Sys.Date()-1
    max: !r Sys.Date()

---

```{r setup, include=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx32000m")
dt_start=as.character(as.Date(params$dts))
dt_end=as.character(as.Date(params$dte))

print(dt_start)
print(dt_end)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `lubridate` package has some nice functions for this. Here's an example using `floor_date`.

````
---
title: "Sample Markdown"
author: "ABC"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
tables: yes
output: html_document
params:
  dts: 
    label: "Start Date"
    input: date
    value: !r lubridate::floor_date(Sys.Date(), 'week')
    max: !r Sys.Date()
  dte: 
    label: "End Date"
    input: date
    value: !r Sys.Date()-1
    max: !r Sys.Date()
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(lubridate)
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")
dt_start=params$dts
dt_end=params$dte

print(dt_start)
print(dt_end)
```
````

Comment: floor_date(Sys.Date(), 'week') doesn't seem to work in the yaml header. Is this code working for you? I am still not getting the week start date in dt_start

Comment: Have you installed the `lubridate` package and loaded it?

Comment: yes, I have the package installed but it still doesn't seem to work. Is it now possible in Base R?